# Best machine learning solution for recommendations based on parameters

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, recommendation-engine

I'm looking for solution that will help me to recommend best matching records for my existing database. I consider to use machine learning for this task.

I have a set of data which describe user choices for movies:
movie, age, gender, movie_rating (0-10) (in future there will be more parameters)

Then what i would would like to get is a solution that helps me to find best movie recommendations by parameters. So input will be user with:
20 years old, male, movie rating 8+

And i result i would like to receive best matching movies for this parameters.

Im considering decision forest regression but maybe there are some other way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is no straight forward algo for your problem because you add multiple features like age,sex,rating in into it.For accomplishing your goal you may use multiple low-rank matrix factorization algorithm like SVD or ALS to find the missing values for a matrix(Collaborative filtering ).Then you need to apply classification algorithm to classify 8+ rating movies with age(20+),sex (male) and take their intersection point.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to use [matrix factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34500546/2838606) to find the missing values for a matrix. For your problem, a lot of users will not have movie ratings for many of the movies in the data base. So you can use matrix factorization to fill (approximate) that matrix and then, based on the scores given to different movies, will recommend movies to the users.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, just use Naive Bayes. It'll get you to 80%+ accuracy in tests, and for things like movie recommendations, it's not as testable for 100% accuracy.